# Optimizing MySQL Query Performance for 'ARCHIVED' Status Selection

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlperformance

I have a table named "article" containing 1,145,141 records with various fields including

```
"id," "uiqPID," "tenant," "status," "title," "body," "user_id," "category_id," "created_at," and "updated_at."
```

The "status" column can have one of three values: 'PUBLISHED,' 'DRAFT,' or 'ARCHIVED,' with the following counts:

- PUBLISHED: 2
- DRAFT: 26,145
- ARCHIVED: 1,118,993

I have set up the following indexes:

1. PRIMARY index on 'id'
2. article_abstract_unq_id index on 'uiqPID'
3. article_abstract_unq_id index on 'tenant'
4. article_status_idx index on 'status'
5. idx_composite_search index on 'id'
6. idx_composite_search index on 'uiqPID'
7. idx_composite_search index on 'created_at'

My issue is with the performance of the following query, which took 5.7 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM 
    article a
WHERE 
    a.status = 'ARCHIVED'
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

However, if I remove the WHERE condition or change it to a.status = 'DRAFT', the query completes within 1 second.

Upon inspecting the query plan, I noticed the difference in execution strategies. With the 'ARCHIVED' or 'DRAFT' status filter, the plan shows:

```
key: article_status_idx
Extra: Using index condition; Using filesort
```

But without the 'ARCHIVED' filter, the plan simply states:

```
key:
Extra: Using filesort
```

My question is: How can I optimize the query performance for filtering on 'ARCHIVED' status, ensuring it executes faster than the current 5.7 seconds, similar to the queries without this condition or with 'DRAFT' status?

Comment: What does the `type` and `rows` columns of the query plan show? Is it examining 1.1 million rows when you query for archived rows? Do you think this should take the same amount of time as the query that examines 26k rows when you query for draft rows?

Comment: @BillKarwin - do you think it will take 5.7 seconds to scan 1.1 million rows and that also indexed?

Comment: It probably isn't using the index, because you are searching for a value that occurs on 97.7% of the rows. If the `type` column of the query plan shows "ALL" then it's doing a table-scan, not using the index. The `key:` being blank also indicates this.

Comment: For the same reason that the index at the back of a book doesn't include common words that occur on the majority of pages of that book, the MySQL optimizer will skip using an index if it estimates the value you are searching for is too common. It would just end up reading every page of the table anyway, so there's no benefit to the extra step of looking up the pages using the index.

Comment: As for whether it takes 5.7 seconds, it certainly could do that. It depends on the power of your database server, speed of your storage, MySQL tuning options, other processes on the same server, etc.

Comment: When i use `a.status = 'ARCHIVED'` it is using the index `article_status_idx`, yes one million records can take 5.7 seconds, can we do any optimization to fix this?

Comment: A couple of answers have suggested creating a composite index, which should optimize the sorting as well as the row search. You may also need to increase the MySQL Buffer Pool to use more RAM, if you have not done so. Assuming your table uses the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Please show us the indexes; their names don't suffice.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a composite index matching the query exactly:

```
create index idx on article (status, created_at desc);
```

Thus the DBMS can go to status = 'ARCHIVED' in the index, read the first 50 entries and be done with the task.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html

Comment: This is the only answer with the optimal `INDEX`, so I am upvoting it.  This index is "covering" and handles any value for `status` equally well.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experienced is actually what I would expect. writing 1,118,993 number-timestamp tuples into memory takes time, especially if you order the results by `created_at`. You need to test the following:

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM 
    article a
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 1118993;
```

and if the time to execute this query is roughly the same as executing the query with the where clause, then it's not the where clause that causes the performance drop, but ordering the query + loading the results into memory. Run the following as well:

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM 
    article a
LIMIT 0, 1118993;
```

Here we do not even have an order by. If this is similarly slow, then the thing you mainly wait for is to write this stuff into memory.

Anyway, do these measurements and the result will either confirm that the slowness is caused by the where or order by clause, or not. If these clauses cause the slowness, then let me know in the comment section and I will provide ways to optimize that issue. But it's highly probable that the real problem is that you are waiting for the full query to be executed.

Maybe it's better to break the query into partitions and run queries with limit 0, 10000 and then limit 10000, 10000 and so on, so you can work with the first results already while waiting for the others, maybe reducing the frustration of impatient users. But that does not change the fact that loading all this stuff takes time, even though you can make this waiting user-friendlier if the showing of partial results makes some useful sense.

EDIT

You can try creating a (status, created_at) key before you create a copy table, maybe such indexing will be useful for your performance, the idea being to have an indexed order for created_at for each status type.

If all else fails, you could create a table like this:

```
create table article_archive(
    id int primary key,
    created_at timestamp
);

insert into article_archive(id, created_at)
select id, created_at
from article
where `status` = 'ARCHIVE';

ALTER TABLE article_archive ADD INDEX (created_at DESC);
```

And then you can select from `article_archive`, like:

```
select id, created_at
from article_archive
order by created_at desc
limit 50;
```

You can even join that with `article` by `id`.

Comment: sorry it was limit query, I forget to add the limit

Comment: @Unnikrishnan if limiting to 50 is extremely slow, then the reason is either the filter or the order by. If you test without the `where` clause, but with the order by and the limit present, is it similarly slow?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you can index by (status, created_at)

Comment: `SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM 
    article a
ORDER BY a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 1000;`

above query gave the result in 0.719 sec / 0.266 sec

`SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM 
    article a
LIMIT 0, 1000;`

above query gave the result in 0.079 sec / 1.375 sec

Comment: @Unnikrishnan have you tried creating a (status, created_at) index?

Comment: > have you tried creating a (status, created_at) index?

Not yet, yes I will do that.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan I hope that will succeed. But if not, then you can create a copy of just the archives. But if you do so, you will need to maintain that, maybe via an hourly cron job.

Comment: FWIW, MySQL does not understand integers with thousands separators. Write the integer like 1118993 instead of 1,118,993.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the constructive criticism. You are absolutely right, of course, it was just a number paste without looking twice on my part. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: ` (status, created_at)` will work (even without `DESC`), but the Answer did not mention it until the end.

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your comment. Moved that part upwards inside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that may improve speed, try it:

```
SELECT 
    a.id AS id,
    a.created_at AS created_at
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM article
    WHERE status = 'ARCHIVED'
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 50
) AS subquery
JOIN article a ON subquery.id = a.id;
```

Explanation:
This query utilizes a subquery to first identify the id values of the 50 most recent 'ARCHIVED' records based on the created_at column. It then performs a join to retrieve the additional columns (id and created_at) from the main table article. This approach can be beneficial when you want to optimize queries with complex filtering and sorting.

Please ensure that the article_status_idx index on the status column and the idx_composite_search index on the created_at and id columns are well-maintained for efficient execution.

Comment: Even if we only select the ID, it's taking the same amount of time, 5.7 seconds on the first execution and 3.2 seconds on subsequent executions.

Comment: I think because you have a lot of archive status table records it's better not to use this ORDER BY a.created_at DESC and check the time result because you are forcing the whole records to be sorted, so if you want this mode It is better to sort all the records once or create a separate sorted table for the archives and use it, the problem of delay in fetching will be reduced.
(I hope you understand what I mean because you also want to sort and then fetch from it).

Comment: Not a useful reformulation _in this case_.  The derived table (inner query) has to look at `created_at` anyway, so there is no savings by not fetching it until the outer query.